# Postgresql query advice

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I need to find out the amount of people that made their first post during a selected day.
I have a table that contains all the posts that everyone made.
So my logic was to get all the people that did only one post, and this post is done yesterday. I tried some queries, but I still dont feel very comfortable with Postgresql, so please help.

Those are the fields that i have available:

- user_id
- post_id
- post_date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id, min(post_date) 
from table
group by user_id
having min(post_date) = YourSelectedDate
```